# How to get current open activity package name or class name in setting like device administration in android 5 and above?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, device-admin

I Want to lock my device administration setting through my app so how to get package name or class name of device administration in android 5 and above version

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have a specific datatype for storing times, and leaves it up to you whether you want to store them as text, integers, or floating-point values, so you can establish whatever convention works best for you.

For your application where you want the time to be editable by the user I'd suggest looking into the DatePicker and TimePicker widgets, so that you don't have to worry about parsing and formatting the time as text, and then the Java Calendar class for converting the data from those into a simple value that you can put in the database (I'd suggest using the getTimeInMillis() method to convert it into a integer)